# Using a JavaScript string to search for results inside a query - Why does it not return results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Using parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

The first code block captures in a variable the input from a user after they click on a user name. For example this maybe "dave".

The second code block is meant to check if the name "friendNameActivity" exists in the parse data browser. It does this by comparing it to a pointer field for username which is held in the class "ClassA".

At the moment no results are being returned. However there should be at least 2 records found.

Are there restrictions using a string to search against the parse db? or have I missed something?

THIS CODE CAPTURES USERS INPUT

```
var friendNameActivity;
        $(document).ready(function() {  
    $(document).on('click','.username', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        friendNameActivity = $(this).text();
              //friendNameActivity = $(this).text();
           // console.log(friendNameActivity);
            friendFeed();
    });                     
                        });
```

---

PARSE QUERY

```
friendNameActivity = $(this).text();

function friendFeed() {

var FriendFeeds = Parse.Object.extend("ClassA");
var query = new Parse.Query(FriendFeeds);
query.include('_User');
query.equalTo('username', friendNameActivity); // find users that match 

    query.find({
        success: function (rules) {


    }
            });
}
```

Comment: Is the username field also on your FriendFeeds class or just on User?

Comment: @RyanDuffy hi, I've created a new question that better explains this. I'll close this question shortly. You can see it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815787/why-do-no-results-returned-after-the-query-runs-using-a-string-variable