# Why do no results returned after the query runs using a string variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

Updated. Added screen shots.

I've added two screen shots, the first using "current user" which makes the below code function correctly. The 2nd screen shot is using the string variable "FriendName". When using this it doesn't look like the pointer is working correctly and linking back to the _USer class ?

[image]

[image]
The below successfully collects a string called "friendName" after the user clicks on the username and stores it in a variable.

I then want to query a class called "myBadge" that holds Badgename, and username (username is a pointer to the class _User).

The result should be to return uploads made my the user stored under "friendName" At the moment nothing is being returned, when 2 results at least should be.

Not sure what I have done wrong?

A link is here to the current page with issue http://kudosoo.com/friendslist.html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '.username', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                friendName = $(this).text();
                //console.log(friendName);
                friendFeed();
            });
        });



        function friendFeed() {
            friendActivity = $('friendName').text();
            console.log(friendName);
            var FriendFeeds = Parse.Object.extend("myBadge");
            var query = new Parse.Query(FriendFeeds);
            query.include('_User');
            query.equalTo('username', friendName); // find users that match


            query.find({
                success: function (rules) {

                    imageURLs = [];
                    Username = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                        var object = rules[i];
                        imageURLs.push(object.get("BadgeName"));
                        Username.push(object.get("username"));
                    }

                    for (var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++) {
                        $('#UserImg').append("<img class='images' src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");
                        $('#Username').append("<div class='username'>'" + Username[j] + "'</div>");
                    }

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    //If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }

            });
        }



         </script>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="UserImg"></div>
<div id="Username"></div>
```

Comment: debug your server side code and check if the call is returning the items.

Comment: This is parse.com there is no server side code, everything is done from the HTML page

Comment: the username field is a string, not a pointer... and include should be passed the column name that has a pointer to another object, not the class name.

Comment: Ok, I can change the include, but the string is not held in the parse backend its only stored within the JS, so how could I convert this string to a pointer?